# Mixing string with query MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to output a string plus certain values I have obtained from the database. For example, in Microsoft Server 2008, the following ran the way I wanted it to:

```
SELECT 
'SELECT c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, '''
+ NAME + ''' db FROM ' + NAME 
+ '.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN ' + NAME 
+ 
'.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like ''%password%'' AND type = ''U'' UNION'
  FROM SYS.DATABASES
```

Returning the following:

```
SELECT c.NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS colName, 
       o.NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS tableName, 
       'master'                                    db 
  FROM MASTER.SYS.ALL_COLUMNS AS c 
       INNER JOIN MASTER.SYS.ALL_OBJECTS o 
               ON c.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID 
 WHERE c.NAME LIKE '%password%' 
       AND TYPE = 'U' 
UNION 
SELECT c.NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS colName, 
       o.NAME COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS tableName, 
       'tempdb'                                    db 
  FROM TEMPDB.SYS.ALL_COLUMNS AS c 
       INNER JOIN TEMPDB.SYS.ALL_OBJECTS o 
               ON c.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID 
 WHERE c.NAME LIKE '%password%' 
       AND TYPE = 'U' 
UNION
```

But when I try a similar thing in MySQL:

```
 SELECT 
'SELECT c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, '''
+ DB + ''' db FROM ' + DB 
+ '.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN ' + DB 
+ 
'.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like ''%password%'' AND type = ''U'' UNION'
  FROM DB
```

It returns only blank lines of the records that I want. Can anyone help?

Comment: What **actual** query do you perform?

Comment: @zerkms I want to create the query I want to do by using the method described, if that makes sense. So first get the DB name using the SELECT DB FROM DB then the result of that query will be another query I will run seperately.

Comment: it works in the opposite way: at first you compose the query that works with static values, and **only after that** you're trying to build similar one in runtime

Comment: try removing the collations. They're probably different.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more @zerkms ?

Comment: @Alias: write a query that returns just data, without concatenation and other complicated things. Just a plain query with SELECT + FROM + WHERE and nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you need the `concat` function in instead of the `+` operator:

```
SELECT concat(
'SELECT c.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS colName, o.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS tableName, '''
, DB , ''' db FROM ' , DB 
, '.sys.all_columns as c INNER JOIN ' , DB 
, 
'.sys.all_objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id WHERE c.name like ''%password%'' AND type = ''U'' UNION'
)  FROM DB
```